# `sig` lines in my GPG key, what are they for, and how to remove?

Tags: gnupg

In [this GPG key of mine](http://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?search=0x4311D0FB042CB88F&fingerprint=on&op=vindex), there I can see lines:

```
sig  sig  4311d0fb042cb88f 2019-03-08T17:59:45Z ____________________ ____________________ [selfsig]
sig  sig  4311d0fb042cb88f 2019-03-08T17:59:45Z ____________________ ____________________ [selfsig]
sig  sig  9710b89bca57ad7c 2019-03-23T12:00:14Z 2019-04-06T12:00:14Z ____________________ 9710b89bca57ad7c
sig  sig  9710b89bca57ad7c 2019-04-05T12:00:15Z 2019-04-19T12:00:15Z ____________________ 9710b89bca57ad7c
sig  sig  9710b89bca57ad7c 2019-04-18T12:00:23Z 2019-05-02T12:00:23Z ____________________ 9710b89bca57ad7c
sig  sig  9710b89bca57ad7c 2019-05-02T00:00:24Z 2019-05-16T00:00:24Z ____________________ 9710b89bca57ad7c
sig  sig  9710b89bca57ad7c 2019-05-15T12:00:17Z 2019-05-29T12:00:17Z ____________________ 9710b89bca57ad7c
sig  sig  9710b89bca57ad7c 2019-05-29T00:00:19Z 2019-06-12T00:00:19Z ____________________ 9710b89bca57ad7c
sig  sig  9710b89bca57ad7c 2019-06-11T12:00:23Z 2019-06-25T12:00:23Z ____________________ 9710b89bca57ad7c
sig  sig  9710b89bca57ad7c 2019-06-25T00:00:21Z 2019-07-09T00:00:21Z ____________________ 9710b89bca57ad7c
sig  sig  9710b89bca57ad7c 2019-07-08T12:00:21Z 2019-07-22T12:00:21Z ____________________ 9710b89bca57ad7c
```

What do they serve for, and can I remove them somehow?

Many thanks for your help